# How to say “chopped cucumber”?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

I want to say chopped cucumber. I find that cucumber is *concombre* in French.

To chop is *hacher*. Its adjective is then *haché* (or *hachée*).
I expected a chopped cucumber to be:

> un concombre haché

But it seems my conclusion is wrong, can you explain me please?

Comment: Is your question about using proper grammar or about the choice of words?

Comment: About using the proper words

Comment: Concombre tranché. Hâché is more like chopped.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your context, it could be *en tranches* (sliced), *émincé* (chopped ), *en dés* (diced). Chopped seems to be the hyperonym for English...

Answer (score 3):

"Haché" est généralement utilisé pour la viande ou d'autres aliments coupés en très petits morceaux (un steak haché, hacher des oignons, etc.).

Pour des concombres, j'utiliserais plutôt "concombres en tranches" ou "dés de concombre" selon la forme qu'ont les morceaux. On s'attend alors à de jolis morceaux réguliers et esthétiques, alors que si tu dis "concombre haché", j'ai l'impression que tu l'as massacré, le pauvre !

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais du « concombre taillé en dés ». Mais il y a d'autres [techniques de coupe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupe_%28cuisine%29).

Answer (score 1):

Au vue des photos pour « chopped cucumber » les traductions pourraient être :
« concombre taillé en dés » comme dit par @Stéphane Gimenez 
ou « émincé de concombre  »

Answer (score 1):

En termes culinaires, on peut dire "**faire une brunoise de concombres**" pour "tailler en dés des concombres".
[image]".

Answer (score 0):

`Hacher` est un terme fort, violent, ainsi on parle de viande hachée, d'oignons hachés...

Ce qui se rapproche le plus de l'action `hacher` est ici `trancher` ou `couper en tranches`

Seulement, une `tranche` se rapporte généralement plutôt aux produits finis, généralement de la viande comme `une tranche de jambon, une tranche de rôti, une tranche de pâté...`

Dans le contexte d'un légume on parle de `rondelles`.
Coupé moins grossièrement que si c'était haché, plus esthétique;

Il paraît judicieux de parler ici de:

> Concombre coupé en rondelles.

et donc de:

> Rondelle de concombre.

Comment: Bonne réponse détaillée, mais je pense que selon le contexte, l'émincé et les dés sont tout aussi recevables. _Chop_ me paraît plus vague que le mot français, il recouvre à mon sens plusieurs formes de découpe (et non, il n'y a aucun rapport avec mon pseudo).